# Flask: how to use cx_Oracle.SessionPool created once in __init.py__.create_app() in routes (other .py files)

Tags: python, flask, database-connection, cx-oracle

I have a simple Flask app like this :

**simple_app/lib/oracle.py:**

```
import cx_Oracle
from flask import current_app

def create_pool():
    # Create session pool
    pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user=current_app.config['USER'],
                                 password=current_app.config['PASSWD'],
                                 dsn=current_app.config['DSN'],
                                 min=4,
                                 max=10,
                                 increment=1,
                                 threaded=True,
                                 getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT)
    return pool
```

**simple_app/routes/**init**.py:**

```
from .hello import hello_bp
from .oracle_pdb_backup import oracle_pdb_backup_bp

def init_app(app):
    app.register_blueprint(hello_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(oracle_pdb_backup_bp)
```

**simple_app/routes/hello.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

hello_bp = Blueprint('hello', __name__)

@hello_bp.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])
def hello_get():
    return jsonify(message = f'hello world!'), 200
```

**simple_app/routes/oracle_pdb_backup.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
from ..lib.oracle import *

oracle_pdb_backup_bp = Blueprint('oracle_pdb_backup', __name__)

@oracle_pdb_backup_bp.route('/oracle/pdb/backup', methods=['GET'])
def oracle_pdb_backup_post():

    pool = ?????? how to access pool defined at app creation ??????
    # Acquire a connection from the pool
    connection = pool.acquire()
    # Use the pooled connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from dual')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    # Release the connection to the pool
    db_pool.release(connection)
    return jsonify(message = result), 200
```

**simple_app/**init**.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

from .lib.oracle import *
from .routes import *

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.secret_key = 'dev'
    app.config.from_object('configSIMPLE')

    with app.app_context():
       create_pool()
    routes.init_app(app)
    return app
```

**I start the app with the following commands :**

```
export PATH=~/python3/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/instantclient_19_12
cd ~/myapps
export FLASK_RUN_HOST=`hostname`
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8080
export FLASK_APP=simple_app
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

How can I create the cx_Oracle.SessionPool **ONCE** in create_app() and use it in all my routes

Note : the pool is created in create_pool() function in simple_app/lib/oracle.py

First, I don't know if :

```
with app.app_context():
   create_pool()
```

is the correct way to initialize the pool at app creation ?

Second, how to use the created pool in my routes ?

see the following line in simple_app/routes/oracle_pdb_backup.py:

```
pool = ?????? how to access pool defined at app creation ??????
```

Could you please tell me what I should modify to make it work.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Maybe I could use a blueprint for that?

Comment: I tried to define pool like that in __init__.py :

    with app.app_context():
       global pool
       pool = create_pool()
but I still have the following error when trying to use pool in simple_app/routes/oracle_pdb_backup.py
`    connection = pool.acquire()
NameError: name 'pool' is not defined`